# Call to a member function associate() on a non-object

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Error Message: http://puu.sh/d4l0F/5b0ac07e68.png

I've even saved the $transportation object before trying to create associations. I've verified that both $transporation, $from and $to are all their respective objects and they are.

I'm sure I'm missing something stupid here but I'm out of ideas.

My code:

```
class RideBuilder implements RideBuilderInterface
{
    public function create(Advance $advance)
    {
        $ride = new Ride;
        if($ride->validate(Input::all())) {
            $ride->save();

            $to = Location::find(Input::get('dropoffLocation'));
            $from = Location::find(Input::get('pickupLocation'));

            $transportation = new Transportation;
            $transportation->save();

            $transportation->transportable()->associate($ride);
            $transportation->to()->associate($to);
            $transportation->from()->associate($from);

            $event = new Event;
            $event->start = Input::get('ridePickUpTime');
            $event->save();

            $event->eventable->save($transportation);
            $event->subjectable->save($advance);
        } 
        return $ride;
    }
}
```

Location Model:

```
class Location extends Elegant
{
protected $table = 'locations';

public $rules = array(
    'label'         => 'required|min:2',
    'street'        => 'required',
    'city'          => 'required',
    'state'         => 'required',
    'type'          => 'required',
);

public function advance()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Booksmart\Booking\Advance\Model\Advance');
}

public function locationable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}

}
```

Transportation Model:

```
class Transportation extends Elegant
{
    protected $table = 'transportations';

    public function event()
    {
        $this->morphOne('Booksmart\Component\Event\Model\Event');
    }

    public function start_location()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('Booksmart\Component\Location\Model\Location', 'start_location');
    }

    public function end_location()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('Booksmart\Component\Location\Model\Location', 'end_location');
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you implement the belongsTo 'transportable' relationship on the `Transportation` model?

Comment: @SteveBauman `moprhTo` rather than `belongsTo`, but yeah, that must be the problem.

Comment: Ah that has to be it! I'll make as an answer once I can test. Thank you.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I had a similar issue. I made the stupid mistake of not adding the "return" in the relationship method!

Make sure you return the relationship... Obviously this will **not** work:

```
public function medicineType() 
   {
      $this->belongsTo('MedicineType', 'id');
   }
```

This is the **correct** way:

```
public function medicineType() 
   {
      return $this->belongsTo('MedicineType', 'id');
   }
```

Easy to miss, hard to debug...

Comment: Thank you forgot to leave my answer. This was the answer.

Comment: Oh damn yeah I missed it too :)

Comment: This just saved me 2 hours of useless debug time.